# Percentage format issue

Tags: c#, .net

I'm formatting numbers using CultureInfo like below:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureISOCode, false);
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = GetCurrencySymbol(currencyISOCode);
doubleValue.ToString(stringFormat, culture)
```

I've got tests that check whether string is properly formatted.
Running test for "en-US" culture and p1 stringFormat on my local PC works fine and returns eg. 12.1%, but running the same test on Azure DevOps returns 12.1 % and test fails.
Running any currency-related tests works fine and results are correct.
What can I do to avoid other environments affecting the result?

GetCurrencySymbol method:

```
private static string GetCurrencySymbol(string currencyISOCode)
{
    string symbol = string.Empty;
    foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
        if (string.Equals(ri.ISOCurrencySymbol, currencyISOCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return ri.CurrencySymbol;
        }
    }
    return symbol;
}
```

Comment: What is `GetCurrencySymbol`?

Comment: can you test with an invariant culture?

Comment: @JohnWu added GetCurrencySymbol method body to question

Comment: @DanielA.White I tested with invariant culture, on both environments it returned 12.1 % - so it worked properly

Comment: instead of passing LCID to RegionInfo() pass TwoLetterISOLanguageName

Comment: @ShiljoPaulson it causes exception: 'The region name aa should not correspond to neutral culture; a specific culture name is required. (Parameter 'name')'